# Disable the parameter name next to the value

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have a problem, I can't find the setting that allows me to disable the parameter name from next to the value, in this case, "name" and "seatsNum", which are actually the names of the parameter. They are grayed out and I can't find the setting to not display them.

Example of the problem:

[image: example of problem]

Comment: "Display parameter hints" is what you're looking for. Some other people like me, wants to enable this feature. Thanks for asking the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be found under:

`Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Inline Hints > Display inline parameter name hints`

[image: Options dialog]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I solved the problem by turning off inline hints unless I hold down ctrl + alt

Answer (score 2):

If one uses resharper and the hints are coming from there, double click on ctrl key to toggle it on/off.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn them off on a method by right-clicking on the parameter hint itself (At least in Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 Version 17.5.1)

and picking: Hide for this method.

I have no idea how to get them back though... So if anyone knows that'd be great.

I guess you could just open the file in a text editor if its the parameter hint is interfering with doing a cut/copy with the mouse. Clicking on a thingy and Ctrl+W also is handy as it selects the whole thingy.