# Turn off visual studio 2022 setting for dynamic field suggestions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I'm encountering a slight annoyance in Visual Studio 2022 that I'm hoping someone can help me with. In the editor window, VS 2022 has a feature that displays the data type and name of variables as shown in this screenshot. While this can be helpful in some cases, I find it distracting and would like to disable it.

I've searched through the settings but couldn't find an option to turn off this feature. Can someone please guide me on how to disable this feature or point me to configurations that might help achieve this?

Thanks in advance for your assistance!
[image: vs 2022 code sample]

Edit 1:
I had already tried [Disable the parameter name next to the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73421303/disable-the-parameter-name-next-to-the-value) but this hide parameter name in methods. I want to hide filed where I am using var as type.

Comment: What about if you scroll down that options page and disable "Display inline type hints"? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74968339/1043380

Answer (score 1):

You can use the hotkey <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to toggle inline hint types on or off.